# How does the variable scope in BitBake works

Tags: variables, scope, yocto, bitbake

I use Yocto and I was wondering how the variable scope works in a BitBake recipe:

My recipe looks like:

```
SRC_URI += "file://something"

python do_fetch_prepend() {
    d.appendVar("SRC_URI", "https://www.bla.com/resource.tar")
    bb.error("SRC_URI_1: %s " % d.getVar("SRC_URI"))
    d.setVar("TEST_VAR", "test")
}

python do_unpack_append() {
    bb.error("SRC_URI_2: %s " % d.getVar("SRC_URI"))
    bb.error("TEST_VAR: %s " % d.getVar("TEST_VAR"))
}
```

I run `bitbake -v -c unpack myrecipe`

`SRC_URI_1` is printed as expected:"file://something [https://www.bla.com/resource.tar"](https://www.bla.com/resource.tar%22)
`SRC_URI_2` is printed as: "file://something"
`TEST_VAR` is printed as: None

It looks like setting/changing a variable in datastore (`D`) is only done in the scope of the `do_fetch`. Is this expected behaviour, because I read in the documentation that `D` is global variable.

If this is expected behaviour, is there away to change global variables in a task of a recipe?

The reason behind the question is that I need another native-recipe before I can add the extra URI to the `SRC_URI`. I tried first Inline Python Variable Expansion, but the BitBake parser already expanse the variable before the native recipe is put in 'native directory'. So I try to change the `SRC_URI` during fetch task and I 'load' my native recipe as follow:

```
python () {
  d.appendVarFlag('do_parse', 'depends', 'my-recipe-native:do_populate_sysroot')
}
```

In the `do_fetch_prepend` I use this native recipe which gives me the correct URL, which I wanted to append to the `SRC_URI`. So the fetching, unpacking, cleaning, etc works. It looks like the fetching works, but the unpacking not because the `SRC_URI` is not updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a given task, variable changes are only local. This means `do_unpack` does not "*see*" a change made by the `do_fetch` task.

This is necessary to allow some tasks to rerun when others are covered by sstate, to ensure things are deterministic.

If you really want to do what you describe, you'd need something like a `prefunc` for the tasks where you need to modify `SRC_URI`.

```
python myprefunc() {
    d.appendVar("SRC_URI", "https://www.bla.com/resource.tar")
}
do_fetch[prefuncs] += "myprefunc"
do_unpack[prefuncs] += "myprefunc"
```

However note that whilst this will do some of what you want, source archives, license manifests and sstate checksums may not work correctly since you're "*hiding*" source data from bitbake and this data is only present at task execution time, not parse time.

Comment: That makes sense and indeed adding the function call to every task is something I want to prevent. There is no way to install a native recipe before parsing starts? Or even better is there a way without patching Yocto to add a fetcher? Or can I append an existing fetcher?

Comment: @Richard Purdie - but what if I wish, for example, to set the `FILES_${PN}` variable within some task (`do_install` for example) - will it affect other tasks performed later (in my case `do_package`)? Meaning, will the `do_package` (or any other task that is AFTER the `do_install`) will "see" the `FILES_${PN}` with the values set in the `do_install` task?

Comment: The system simply doesn't work in that way. If you want to save and share something between tasks you'd usually write it somewhere into WORKDIR such as the sysroot and read it back in.

Comment: @RichardPurdie - I need to set the `FILES` variable with a list of files that must be composed during some task BEFORE the `do_package()`.I implemented the `python do_package_prepend()` and set there a string with single space separator between one another, so at the end of this Python function `FILES` is something like the following: `/some/path/to/file1 /some/path/to/file2'. However, when the default (I did not change it) `do_package` function (task) is called I get the error:`QA Issue: my_recipe: Files/directories were installed but not shipped...` - How can I resolve it?