# How to set global BitBake variable in one task so that it will be noticable in another task?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe, software-packaging

I recently started to work with Yocto and now trying to understand how exactly "global" variables of some recipe work.
Till now I had a recipe as follows:

```
# my-recipe.bb
FILES_${PN} += "/lib/mypackage1/package1-shared-object.so"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/lib/mypackage1/
    install ${S}/mypackage1/* ${D}/lib/mypackage1/
}

RPROVIDES_${PN} += "package1-shared-object.so"
```

This works fine - i.e. - the `package1-shared-object.so` file was installed correctly within the `/lib/mypackage1/package1-shared-object.so` path of my image.

Now I need to install under the `/lib` folder some ***two more*** shared-objects of two additional packages, so eventually I will have:

`/lib/mypackage1/package1-shared-object.so`

`/lib/mypackage2/package2-shared-object.so`

`/lib/mypackage3/package3-shared-object.so`

The list of mypackages is given to my recipe via the variable `MY_RECIPE_PACKAGES_LIST`, i.e. - it is: `MY_RECIPE_PACKAGES_LIST = "mypackage1 mypackage2 mypackage3"`

So now my updated `do_install` task in my recipe is as follows:

```
# my-recipe.bb

do_install() {

    // iterate over the list of packages and for each install the respective shared object in the desired location:
    for package_name in ${MY_RECIPE_PACKAGES_LIST}; do
        install -d ${D}/lib/${package_name}
        # the shared-objectX is the only file under: ${S}/package_name/
        cp ${S}/${package_name}/* ${D}/lib/${package_name}
    done
}
```

The `do_install` task works fine (I look into the `image` folder of `my-recipe` and I see all 3 shared-object's in their desired location).

HOWEVER, when I run the recipe, I get the following error as part of the `do_package` task.

> ERROR: my-recipe do_package: QA Issue: my-recipe: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
> /lib/mypackage1/package1-shared-object.so
> /lib/mypackage2/package2-shared-object.so
> /lib/mypackage3/package3-shared-object.so
> Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
> my-recipe: 3 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
> ERROR: my-recipe do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.

I looked at the this Q&A: [How does the variable scope in BitBake works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031437/how-does-the-variable-scope-in-bitbake-works)

and added the `python myprefunc` to my-recipe so it is now:

```
# my-recipe.bb

do_install() {

    // iterate over the list of packages and for each install the respective shared object in the desired location:
    for package_name in ${MY_RECIPE_PACKAGES_LIST}; do
        install -d ${D}/lib/${package_name}
        # the shared-objectX is the only file under: ${S}/${package_name}
        install -d ${S}/${package_name}/* ${D}/lib/${package_name}
    done
}

python myprefunc() {
     # for I did it "manually, offcourse iterating here is a better approach.
    files_pn = "/lib/mypackage1/package1-shared-object.so /lib/mypackage2/package2-shared-object.so /lib/mypackage3/package3-shared-object.so"
    d.appendVar("FILES_${PN}", files_pn)
}

do_package[prefuncs] += "myprefunc"
```

**BUT** still I get the same error for the `do_package` task.

The questions are:

1. How can I overcome it ("pass"/ complete successfully the `do_package` task and the entire recipe)?
2. How do I define the `FILES_${PN}` in my recipe (if at all) "outside" of any task?
3. What about the `RPROVIDES_${PN}` - how it should be set and when (in which task)?